# First Empty Row in Google Script with dynamic column range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get the first empty row of a column. The number of this column is determined by a variable.

```
var values = pnl.getRange('A:A').getValues();      //Returns 2D array
var firstEmptyRow = 4;
while(values[firstEmptyRow]&&values[firstEmptyRow][0]!=""){
  firstEmptyRow++;
}
firstEmptyRow++;

pnl.getRange(firstEmptyRow,1+24*month).setValue(firstEmptyRow);
```

This works fine, however in this function the range of the column is always the same.

Here is what I'm trying to do

```
var lastRow = pnl.getLastRow()
var columnRange = pnl.getRange(4,1+24*month,lastRow,1);

var values = columnRange.getValues();      //Returns 2D array?
var firstEmptyRow = 4;
while(values[firstEmptyRow]&&values[firstEmptyRow][0]!=""){
  firstEmptyRow++;
}
firstEmptyRow++;

pnl.getRange(firstEmptyRow,1+24*month).setValue(firstEmptyRow);
```

I don't get any errors, the code simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You can use the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method after you have [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)ten the `values` array to get the first empty cell of a particular column.

**Solution:**

Based on your first code snippet:

```
var startingRow = 4;
var values = pnl.getRange(startingRow,1+24*month,pnl.getLastRow(),1).getValues();      
var firstEmptyRow = values.flat().indexOf('') + startingRow;
pnl.getRange(firstEmptyRow,1+24*month).setValue(firstEmptyRow);
```

Keep in mind this returns the array index. So the actual row of the cell will be `firstEmptyRow+1` because indexes in JavaScript start from `0`.

Comment: I've read that the method I've implemented is the fastest so I would like to keep it

Comment: @MatteoMarinari A loop that iterates on every element is never faster than the `findIndex`.

Comment: `var firstEmptyRow = values.flat().findIndex(c=>c=='');` I dont' get what this does and i don't see where in the code i have the formula that gives me the column i want to consider

Comment: The code you suggested only checks the column A. I want the code to scan the column whose index (number of the column in the sheet) is equal to 1+24*month

Comment: @MatteoMarinari please check my updated answer

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Thanks for your comment, I realized that I was planning to use `indexOf` and not `findIndex` .

Comment: It gives me an errore with the flat() method

Comment: @MatteoMarinari if you are using the legacy editor go to `Run` => `Enable V8`, if you are using the new editor click on `Project Settings` and then check the box: `Enable Chrome V8 runtime` . If that is not working, then tell me what is the error you are getting.

Comment: Alredy Enabled, still gives me error, how do i see what error it is? I'm not sure but is seems like the method is not declared

Comment: @MatteoMarinari give the exact description of the error. I can't help you otherwise .

Comment: @MatteoMarinari how do you execute the code? The editor should show the exact error message after the execution.

Comment: I don't runt it, it's an on edit function. I can send you the full code fi you want.

Comment: @MatteoMarinari go to `executions` and you will find the error message.

Comment: It dosn't give me any error. It shows completed but it dosn't write anything in the cell. The flat() method is underlined with red and says "can't find the declaration"

Comment: Share the sheet with me. Create a public url and share your sheet. I can't reproduce your issue. @MatteoMarinari

Comment: I've written `var firstEmptyRow = values.join().split(",").findIndex(c=>c=='') + 1;` and works,I'm not sure why but it seems that in goole sheet, or at least in mine, the method flat() is not provided. Thank you so much, It's the second time you help me today ;)

Comment: @Marios I've found asmall bug in this code. If i write `var values = pnl.getRange(4,1+24*month,pnl.getLastRow(),1).getValues();  ` it dosn't return the first empty row after the 4th row, it returns 2 for some unknown reason. The first cell of the column is empty, the second is a union of cell containing the month, the third is a union of cell caintating some other stuff, the 4th is the title, I wanna find the first empty row after the title

Comment: @MatteoMarinari that is not a bug, you just need to add `4` instead of `1`: `var firstEmptyRow = values.flat().indexOf('') + 4;` If you want a more dynamic code, create a variable with the name `startingRow` and use that in both places. See my updated answer.

Comment: That way i just take the 3rd line after the first empty row, i still wanna get the first empty row but i want to ignore the first 4 lines. I tried  `var firstEmptyRow = valoriColonnaCliente.join().split(",").splice(0,4).findIndex(c=>c=='') + 5;
` but it dosn't work

Comment: @MatteoMarinari could you please post a separate question regarding this issue so other readers can participate in the discussion as well. Stackoverflow does not allow for follow up questions unfortunately. Sorry for the incovenience and your understanding.